# Elasticsearch unassigned shards : corrupt_index_exception, no_valid_shard_copy, e_o_f_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, elastic-cloud, azure-elastic-sharding

I am using helm chart for elastic 7.12.0 cluster (2 master , 2 data) deployment on K8s, with a stateful-set (for persistence i have a volume claim).
getting a lot of unassigned shards, where the shards are corrupted.

*"unassigned_info": {
"reason": "ALLOCATION_FAILED"
"can_allocate": "no_valid_shard_copy"
"type": "corrupt_index_exception"

"caused_by": {
"type": "e_o_f_exception",
"reason": "read past EOF: NIOFSIndexInput(path="/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/q-23aUrvSI6Sy9UPttY3Yw/0/index/_lpy_1.fnm") buffer: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1024 cap=1024] chunkLen: 1024 end: 29477"
}*

has anyone come across this type of scenario / any configuration that i should be aware of wen dealing with persistent volumes for th cluster data?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using glusterfs as storage class?

Comment: Could it be faulty hardware? Are those shards on the same or different physical nodes?

Comment: Side note: you probably don't need dedicated masters unless your cluster grows to 15-20 data nodes

Comment: the issue was we had the wrong storage in our Azure configuration of the setup (helm), we changed it and it hasnt happened yet. i expect it was the issue , leading to persistence trouble.